# Vertical Text in QTextEdit

Tags: qt, qtextedit, qtextdocument, qtextcursor

I need to have vertical text (direction - from bottom to top) in QTextEdit.
The most similar solution I implemented is a replacing horizontal text block with rotated picture (screenshot of original text block) when user presses "rotate" button. But it is a crutch - rorated text become not editable.
Are there more elegant solutions?

Comment: @Nejat I consolidate both horizontal and vertical text within a one page. Primarily it is intended for printing. Some document that must satisfy our corp standards

Comment: Qxt has label and button which can be rotated. But for text edit you should implement it which is so hard.